# Proving that a group generated by x,y and z and a given relation is actually free

Tags: free-groups

I'm trying to show that a group generated by elements $x,y,z$ with a given relation $xyxz^{-2}=1$ (where $1$ is the identity) is in fact a free group.

What are some usual ways of going about this kind of problem? Just hints please!

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is essentially just an expansion of Boris Novikov's solution.)

There is an important technique known as [Tietze transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformation) for manipulating presentations of groups.  The two Tietze transformations are:

1. Add a new relation which can be derived from the existing relations.  Inversely, remove a relation that can be derived from the others.
2. Add a new generator, together with a relation that expresses it in terms of the existing generators.  Inversely, you can remove a generator if this generator only appears in one relation, and this relation defines the generator in terms of other generators.

A special case of (1) is to replace a relation with an equivalent relation.  Technically, this involves two applications of (1): you must first add the new relation, and then remove the original.

Tietze's theorem is that these moves do not change the isomorphism type of a group defined by a presentation.  Moreover, if two finitely presented groups are isomorphic, it is possible to get from the first presentation to the second using a finite sequence of Tietze transformations.

Now, the given group has the following presentation:
$$
\langle x,y,z \mid xyxz^{-2} = 1\rangle.
$$
The given relation is equivalent to the relation $y = x^{-1}z^2 x$, so we can replace it using two Tietze transformations of type (1):
$$
\langle x,y,z \mid y=x^{-1}z^2 x^{-1}\rangle.
$$
We can now use a Tietze transformation of type (2) to remove the generator $y$.  This leaves
$$
\langle x,z \mid -\rangle
$$
which is a presentation for the free group of rank two.

Comment: Does this mean the group is not actually generated by the three elements $x,y,z$?

Answer (score 5):

You have $y=x^{-1}z^2x^{-1}$ from your relation, so $G=\langle x,z\rangle$ without any defining relation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the relations of your problem to the subject of [presentation of groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group), in general, and in particular to the Nielsen-Schreier therorem and [Nielsen transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen_transformation)? This should qualify as one of the "usual ways" of going about this kind of problem at least.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've realized that my question was way to vague. I've edited it and put in the actual relation.